# JQuery - How can I carry on with script after call to modal dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, dialog

I have a script that calls a modal dialogue to get some values from the user.
if is use prompt the user enters a single value and control is passed back to the script.

However, if I open a dialogue it does not return control to the next command in the script.

Can anyone show me where I am going wrong?

This code works (note getWeight call to prompt)

```
$('#scancodebox').change(function () {
        var barcode = '';
        if (this.value.length > 0) {
            barcode = this.value;
            var scancountry = barcode.substring(0, 2);
            var scanherd = barcode.substring(2, 8);
            var scananimal = barcode.substring(8, 14);
            var scandate = barcode.substring(14, 22);
            var scandobday = barcode.substring(14, 16);
            var scandobmonth = barcode.substring(16, 18);
            var scandobyear = barcode.substring(18, 22);
            var scansex = barcode.substring(22, 23);
            var scanbreed = barcode.substring(23);
            var getWeight = prompt("Enter Weight");            

            var scandob = scandobyear + "/" + scandobmonth + "/" + scandobday
            //****************************************************************
            // Calculate Days
            //****************************************************************
            var utcToday = new Date();
            var utcDob = new Date(scandobyear, scandobmonth, scandobday);
            var _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
            var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
            var daysold = Math.round(Math.abs((utcDob.getTime() - utcToday.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
            var scanmoveon = utcToday.getFullYear() + "/" + utcToday.getMonth() + "/" + utcToday.getDate()
            //****************************************************************

            //var scanCountry = substring(barcode, 1, 2);
            //alert(scanCountry);
            //this.value = '';

            var grid = $("#grdSPL").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.dataSource.add({
                Country: scancountry,
                HerdNumberId: scanherd,
                DOB: scandob,
                MoveOn: scanmoveon,
                AnimalId: scananimal,
                BreedId: scanbreed,
                Weight: getWeight,
                NotifyCTS: 1,
                Age: daysold,
                Grade: 2,
                DayTag: Math.floor(Math.random() * 250) + 1,
                Sex: scansex
            });
        }
    }
```

This shows popup but on close does not continue.

```
  $('#scancodebox').change(function () {
        var barcode = '';
        if (this.value.length > 0) {
            barcode = this.value;
            var scancountry = barcode.substring(0, 2);
            var scanherd = barcode.substring(2, 8);
            var scananimal = barcode.substring(8, 14);
            var scandate = barcode.substring(14, 22);
            var scandobday = barcode.substring(14, 16);
            var scandobmonth = barcode.substring(16, 18);
            var scandobyear = barcode.substring(18, 22);
            var scansex = barcode.substring(22, 23);
            var scanbreed = barcode.substring(23);
            //var getWeight = prompt("Enter Weight");
            var retval = $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");

            var scandob = scandobyear + "/" + scandobmonth + "/" + scandobday
            //****************************************************************
            // Calculate Days
            //****************************************************************
            var utcToday = new Date();
            var utcDob = new Date(scandobyear, scandobmonth, scandobday);
            var _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
            var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
            var daysold = Math.round(Math.abs((utcDob.getTime() - utcToday.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
            var scanmoveon = utcToday.getFullYear() + "/" + utcToday.getMonth() + "/" + utcToday.getDate()
            //****************************************************************

            //var scanCountry = substring(barcode, 1, 2);
            //alert(scanCountry);
            //this.value = '';

            var grid = $("#grdSPL").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.dataSource.add({
                Country: scancountry,
                HerdNumberId: scanherd,
                DOB: scandob,
                MoveOn: scanmoveon,
                AnimalId: scananimal,
                BreedId: scanbreed,
                Weight: getWeight,
                NotifyCTS: 1,
                Age: daysold,
                Grade: 2,
                DayTag: Math.floor(Math.random() * 250) + 1,
                Sex: scansex
            });
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Ron

Answer (score 0):

when you call open dialog it's not wait for getting value from user and it's continue to run next command. so you have to wait for closing the dialog and do the rest your code.
try use Bootstrap Dialog (https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/)
and in callback you can do the rest.

i hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will take a look